# Simple assembly hex dump utility for files

Tags: assembly, nasm

I'm reading this book(Assembly language step by step by Jeff Duntemann), and in chapter 9 there's this example:

```
;  Executable name : hexdump1
;  Version         : 1.0
;  Created date    : 4/4/2009
;  Last update     : 4/4/2009
;  Author          : Jeff Duntemann
;  Description     : A simple program in assembly for Linux, using NASM 2.05,
;    demonstrating the conversion of binary values to hexadecimal strings.
;    It acts as a very simple hex dump utility for files, though without the
;    ASCII equivalent column.
;
;  Run it this way:
;    hexdump1 < (input file)  
;
;  Build using these commands:
;    nasm -f elf -g -F stabs hexdump1.asm
;    ld -o hexdump1 hexdump1.o
;


SECTION .bss            ; Section containing uninitialized data
BUFFLEN equ 16      ; We read the file 16 bytes at a time
Buff:   resb BUFFLEN    ; Text buffer itself
SECTION .data           ; Section containing initialised data
HexStr: db " 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00",10
HEXLEN equ $-HexStr
Digits: db “0123456789ABCDEF“

SECTION .text           ; Section containing code
global  _start          ; Linker needs this to find the entry point!
_start:
nop

; Read a buffer full of text from stdin:
Read:
mov eax,3       ; Specify sys_read call
mov ebx,0       ; Specify File Descriptor 0: Standard Input
mov ecx,Buff        ; Pass offset of the buffer to read to
mov edx,BUFFLEN     ; Pass number of bytes to read at one pass
int 80h         ; Call sys_read to fill the buffer
mov ebp,eax     ; Save # of bytes read from file for later
cmp eax,0       ; If eax=0, sys_read reached EOF on stdin
je Done         ; Jump If Equal (to 0, from compare)

; Set up the registers for the process buffer step:
mov esi,Buff        ; Place address of file buffer into esi
mov edi,HexStr      ; Place address of line string into edi
xor ecx,ecx     ; Clear line string pointer to 0

; Go through the buffer and convert binary values to hex digits:
Scan:
xor eax,eax     ; Clear eax to 0

; Here we calculate the offset into the line string, which is ecx X 3
mov edx,ecx     ; Copy the pointer into line string into edx
shl edx,1       ; Multiply pointer by 2 using left shift
add edx,ecx     ; Complete the multiplication X3

; Get a character from the buffer and put it in both eax and ebx:
mov al,byte [esi+ecx]   ; Put a byte from the input buffer into al
mov ebx,eax     ; Duplicate the byte in bl for second nybble

; Look up low nybble character and insert it into the string:
and al,0Fh         ; Mask out all but the low nybble
mov al,byte [Digits+eax]   ; Look up the char equivalent of nybble
mov byte [HexStr+edx+2],al ; Write the char equivalent to line string

; Look up high nybble character and insert it into the string:
shr bl,4        ; Shift high 4 bits of char into low 4 bits
mov bl,byte [Digits+ebx] ; Look up char equivalent of nybble
mov byte [HexStr+edx+1],bl ; Write the char equivalent to line string

; Bump the buffer pointer to the next character and see if we're done:
inc ecx     ; Increment line string pointer
cmp ecx,ebp ; Compare to the number of characters in the buffer
jna Scan    ; Loop back if ecx is <= number of chars in buffer

; Write the line of hexadecimal values to stdout:
mov eax,4       ; Specify sys_write call
mov ebx,1       ; Specify File Descriptor 1: Standard output
mov ecx,HexStr      ; Pass offset of line string
mov edx,HEXLEN      ; Pass size of the line string
int 80h         ; Make kernel call to display line string
jmp Read        ; Loop back and load file buffer again

; All done! Let's end this party:
Done:
mov eax,1       ; Code for Exit Syscall
mov ebx,0       ; Return a code of zero 
int 80H         ; Make kernel call
```

Let's say we've read 16 bytes and the buffer's full.
I have two questions:

1. After we've Scanned all the bytes in the buffer, `ecx` is 16. 
   When the `jna Scan` instruction executes, `ecx` is equal to `ebp` and we jump to `Scan`. What does `mov al,byte [esi+ecx]` move into `al`, since buffer's length is 16, and highest offset number could be 15?
2. What happens when we read, let's say 10 bytes and we write them to `stdout`? Does It just print `HexStr` with 10 new values, and the last 6 values from the previous write?

Comment: Thanks for yo r replies, Ross Ridge and JVene.

Comment: Yes, It's the 3rd edition. 
My second question was in the case when we have for example 26 bytes in the input file. We read 16 bytes in the first iteration, and we're left with 10 bytes in the second iteration.
As you said, I guess the last 6 bytes being written in the second iteration will be previous values from the previous iteration.

By the way, do you guys know a way to contact the author about this possible errors in the code? The book is old now, but It would be easier for other readers to find the erratas on author's web page.

Comment: I also forgot to paste an instruction in my question's code, but I don't think It has anything to do with the errors:
Digits: db “0123456789ABCDEF“.

Sorry, if it mislead anyone.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to me you've found two more errata for the book (it seems it is in 3rd edition, is yours earlier?).

Indeed, `jna` should very likely be `jl`. Garbage would be moved into `al` otherwise, and no doubt you've realized the loop is running through `17`, not `16` bytes.

Your second point is correct, too. The author uses a constant value of 16, so the "tail" logic isn't even there. Unless the book discusses debugging of this sample, you've found two at once. Yes, it would include characters from the previous read, unless the input itself is only 10 bytes and this is the first and only pass through the routine, at which point those 6 bytes would be garbage nonsense (correction, the first pass would show zeros as that is initialized - thanks Ross Ridge).

Comment: Well, they 6 extra bytes would be zeroes on the first pass because the .bss section is zero initialized.